# How to make JavaScript show on a page rather than in a console?

Tags: javascript

I really want to know how to do this, instead of `"james".length` to show in the console, how do I make it show on the webpage? Like having the number 5 showing on the page instead of the console.

Comment: There's tons of good help [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+write+to+web+page).

Answer (score 3):

This will put it in a DIV with `id="somediv"`:

```
document.getElementById("somediv").innerText = "james".length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
document.body.innerHTML = "james".length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a div with id `outputDiv`.

You can print to this div by doing:

```
var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
outputDiv.innerHTML += "james".length;
```

If you want to add individual paragraphs one at a time you can do:

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = "james".length;
outputDiv.appendChild(p);
```